# Displaying composite text in DropDownList (MVC) in a strong-typed form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I've something similar to this:

```
public class employee
{
    Int id;
    String Name;
    String FamilyName;
    String SecondFamilyName;
}  

public class orders
{
    Int id;
    Int employeeid;
    Int amount;
}
```

(an employee can have many orders, orders and employee are related via "employeeid" property)

Strong-typed "create orders" form in MVC:

- A DropDownList will allow me to select the right employee when creating orders.
- The DropDownList should display employee names in a way defined by a third method, that it concatenates "FamilyName SecondFamilyName, Name" for employees that SecondFamilyName is not null and "FamilyName, Name" for the other.

What should I do? Using default VS 2010 templates, the runtime picks "Name" to show in DropDownList. I need the composite name, but I can't figure how to it...

Regards.

Comment: what method are you using to pull your values? is it EF?

Comment: So you are pulling from your reference table and creating a selectlist? And that selectlist is limited to just name/value?

Comment: That's right. I don't know what to do to tell MVC "that value is employeid"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 2,

After working for a couple of hours, I've noticed that, by default, VS 2010 generates a template which is being populated in Create method, with employees id and single names...

So,

Create method:

- add ViewBag.employeeid with the list of (ids, composite names)

Create view:

- replace server side code with

  @Html.DropDownList("employeeid", String.Empty)

That's all. I feel stupid not seeing this so-obvious-thing before...

What do you think, Dave A?

EDIT

Just adding the code used to build the list and the composite name:

**--> Employee html helper, to generate SelectList (with selected item)**

```
public static class employeeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> toSelectListItems(this IEnumerable<employee> Employees, Nullable<Int32> selectedID)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lEmployees = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (employee ee in Employees)
            lEmployees.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = selectedID != null && ee.id == selectedID.Value,
                Text = employeeExtender.getEmployeeNames(pp),
                Value = pp.id.ToString()         
            });

        lEmployees = lEmployees.OrderBy(p => p.Text).ToList();

        return lEmployees;
    }
}
```

**--> Employee extender, to get the composite name**
Using Stringbuilder for performance

```
public class employeeExtender
{
    public static String getEmployeeNames(employee e)
    {
        if (e == null)
            return null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(e.FamilyName.ToLower());

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.SecondFamilyName) && e.SecondFamilyName.Trim() != String.Empty)
            sb.Append(" " + e.SecondFamilyName.ToLower());

        sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(e.Name.ToLower());

        //Capitalize String
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Custom Edit Template for the DropDownList:

```
<select id="employeeid" name="employeeid">
    <option value="">Pick an employee</option>
    @foreach (SelectListItem sli in ViewBag.Employees)
    {
        <option value="@sli.Value">@sli.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

It shows the String I need, and it's bound to employeeid field. I'm able to create new objects and showing the employee names as I want.

Fairly simple, it's hard when someone like me lack of skill in this basic task. MVC is a whole different new world...

Comment: interesting. did it from the client side. very creative. try to master more server side list processing. It may seem like a head-ache now, but c# is more flexible than jscript. for now, as long as it worked, good job.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Dave, I've used the suggestions given in "Custom Editor Template" chapter of the Pro Asp.Net MVC 3 Framework book... (no time yet for finishing the book)